# Прием POST запросов в формате JSON на сервере NODE JS

Tags: node.js

Всем привет!! На данный момент я изучаю серверную часть Node JS и столкнулся с проблемой отправки POST Запросов в формате JSON. Как получить и как обработать данные?

Вот начальный код на чистом Node. Я понимаю что есть альтернатива: "Express", но я очень сильно хочу сделать без фреймворков.

```
const http = require('http');
const { parse } = require("querystring");
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');
let variabel = [];

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    console.log(request.method);
    if (request.method === "GET") {
        console.log(`Запрошенный адрес: ${request.url}`);
        const filePath = request.url.substr(1);
        fs.access(filePath, fs.constants.R_OK, err => {
            // если произошла ошибка - отправляем статусный код 404
            if (err) {
                response.statusCode = 404;
                response.end("Resourse not found!");
            } else {
                fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log(`Запрошенный адрес: ${request.url}`);
      /// Тут должна быть конвертация JSON Формата
    }

}).listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started at 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку `request` это `stream.Readable`, вы можете получить его содержимое стандартными для потоков средствами — через обработчики событий `'data'` и `'end'`. Но, возможно, проще будет сделать колбэк асинхронной функцией и воспользоваться тем, что `stream.Readable` является также асинхронным итератором:

```js
http.createServer(async (request, response) => {
    if (request.method === 'GET') {
        // ...
    } else {
        console.log(`Запрошенный адрес: ${request.url}`);

        request.setEncoding('utf8');
        let json = '';
        for await (const chunk of request) {
          json += chunk;
        }
        const object = JSON.parse(json);
        // ...
    }
});
```